# Code First EF: While searching database table is it possible to retrieve list of items it has in DataModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have this model

```
public class Appointment
{

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }      
}
```

and the Attendee class

```
public class Attendee
{
    public Guid AttendeeId { get; set; }

    public Guid AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Response> Responses { get; set; } 
}
```

and the DbContext class

```
public class DatePickerDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DatePickerDbContext():base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    }

    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

now when i do the query on Appointments table like for example

```
_db.Appointments.Find(appointmentId);
```

shouldn't it lazy load all the attendees too?

Or am I missing some thing in my model?

PS:

**EntityFramework Version** : 6.0.2

**Asp.Net MVC version** : 5.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lazy load a related class, the property in the model should be `virtual` and it shoud be `ICollection`, not `IEnumerable`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
```

Comment: will give it a shot and see the result and let you know

Comment: i changed it virtual but still doesn't load the attendees :(

Comment: should be ICollection rather than IEnumerable, posted it as a answer but +1 for letting me know about the making the field virtual

Comment: You are right it should be `ICollection`, not `IEnumerable`. I didn't noticed that you were using `IEnumerable`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I should change

```
public IEnumerable<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
```

PS:

Simply setting it to virtual `IEnumerable<Attendee>` didn't work for me, had to be virtual `ICollection<Attendee>`